# ORACLE: Looking at different date ranges with one select

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to be able to calculate different age ranges across different as of dates over the course of a year without having to union all.

The query now would be something like this:

```
   SELECT
      to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),'YYYYMM') yrmnth,
      FLOOR(months_between(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),birth_date)/12),
    count(distinct id) members
    from agefile
    WHERE to_char(from_date, 'YYYYMM')<=to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),'YYYYMM') 
    and to_char(thru_date, 'YYYYMM')>=to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),'YYYYMM')
    GROUP BY to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),'YYYYMM'),
    FLOOR(months_between(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)),birth_date)/12)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2)),'YYYYMM') yrmnth,
      FLOOR(months_between(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2)),birth_date)/12),
    count(distinct id) members
    from agefile
    WHERE to_char(from_date, 'YYYYMM')<=to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2)),'YYYYMM') 
    and to_char(thru_date, 'YYYYMM')>=to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2)),'YYYYMM')
    GROUP BY to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2)),'YYYYMM'),
    FLOOR(months_between(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2)),birth_date)/12)

    UNION ALL

and so on...
```

so, instead of passing the agefile 12 times, I want to pass it once, but output 12X number of ages.

Example:

```
yrmnth    age     members
201809     1        100
201809     2        120
201809     3        145
201808     1        56
```

"How many members were age x as of the last day of every month for the last 12 months" would be the business question

Any way to get around passing the file 12 times and doing this with one select?

thank you

Comment: Please edit your post, highlight your SQL and press the `{ }` button

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding an integer, you want to cross join to set of integers.

You could do something like:

```
SELECT ROWNUM as rn FROM agefile
WHERE ROWNUM <= 12
```

Then CROSS JOIN and use `rn*-1` in place of your hard-coded integers:

```
   with cte as (     SELECT ROWNUM as rn
                      FROM agefile
                      WHERE ROWNUM <= 12
                )
    SELECT
      to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,rn*-1)),'YYYYMM') yrmnth,
      FLOOR(months_between(last_day(add_months(sysdate,rn*-1)),birth_date)/12),
      count(distinct id) members
    FROM agefile
    CROSS JOIN cte
    WHERE to_char(from_date, 'YYYYMM')<=to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,rn*-1)),'YYYYMM') 
       and to_char(thru_date, 'YYYYMM')>=to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,rn*-1)),'YYYYMM')
    GROUP BY to_char(last_day(add_months(sysdate,rn*-1)),'YYYYMM'),
       FLOOR(months_between(last_day(add_months(sysdate,rn*-1)),birth_date)/12)
```

In this case it cleans up even better if you cross apply to a list of months rather than integers, and having a pre-built numbers/tally table to join to would make it even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Build your months back days in a with clause and cross join with the table:

```
with months as
(
  select last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1)) as day from dual
  union all
  select last_day(add_months(sysdate, -2)) as day from dual
  union all
  ...
)
select
  to_char(months.day,'yyyymm') yrmnth,
  floor(months_between(months.day, birth_date) / 12),
  count(distinct id) members
from months cross join agefile
where to_char(from_date, 'yyyymm') <= to_char(months.day, 'yyyymm') 
  and to_char(thru_date, 'yyyymm') >= to_char(months.day, 'yyyymm')
group by
  to_char(months.day, 'yyyymm'),
  floor(months_between(months.day, birth_date) / 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query performs a lot of redundant operations and can be cleaned up a lot:

```
WITH m AS(
  SELECT last_day(add_months(sysdate,level-12)) month_end FROM dual CONNECT BY level <=12
)
SELECT
  m.month_end,
  trunc(months_between(af.birth_date, .month_end)) as age_at,
  count(*) as num_mem
FROM
  age_file af
  CROSS JOIN
  m
GROUP BY
  m.month_end,
  trunc(months_between(af.birth_date, .month_end))
```

I couldn't quite work out what the significance of the from date and thru date was, unless it's a filter for active membership, in which case it can probably be expressed as `where m.month_end between af.from_date and af.thru_date`

All the huge amounts of manipulating dates and to charring in your query is unnecessary- no need to go to the extend of calculating the last day of a month if you're then immediately going to chop the day off by tocharring to month only etc.

I recommend you leave the day in the date, because it makes it more clear that the ages expressed are on the last day of the month- I think a lot of people's default assumptions when looking at a month only date would be that it refers to the start of a month

As it stands this query calculates the current month also. If you only want the prior 12 months not including the current month make it -13 in the level query. (Query produces 1 to 12, subtracting 12 means it's -12 to 0. Subtracting 13 makes it -13 to -1)

Comment: WITH m AS(
  SELECT last_day(add_months(sysdate,level-1)) month_end FROM dual CONNECT BY level <=12
) gave me dates in the future....

Comment: Good catch, fixed the typo